# Подтянуть url фотографии объекта с Yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как получить url фотографии объекта в ответ на запрос с координатами или адресом объекта?

Answer (score 0):

API Яндекс.Карт ограниченно работает с данными организаций и может показать по координатам лишь [панорамы](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/panorama_basics). Возможности получить ссылки на отдельные фотографии нет.

Большая часть фотографий привязана к конкретным организациям. Открыть их альбом несложно, используя ссылку вида https://yandex.ru/maps/org/1671141286/gallery/ Но даже в метаданных организаций нет информации о привязанных снимках.